# Laravel relationship is being inserted in the collection

Tags: eloquent

I created the following accessors to check the agency property:

```php
  public function getIsAgencyAttribute() {
       // agency is a boolean value
       return isset( $this->ref->agency ) && $this->ref->agency;
  }

  // relationship
  public function ref() {
       return $this->hasOne(SellerRef::class, 'user_id');
  }
```

I call the append() method:

```php
   $query = User::query();
  
   // a bunch of when conditions...
   // $query->when(...);  
   
   $data = $query->limit( $request->limit ?: config('app.limit_per_page') )->get();

   $data->append('is_agency');

   return response()->json( responseFormat( false, $data ) );
```

expected response:

```json
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "mariana",
      "email": "mariana@email.com",
      "blocked_at": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-03-05T02:44:46.000000Z",
      "is_agency": false
    }
```

current response:

```json
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "mariana",
      "email": "mariana@email.com",
      "blocked_at": null,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2021-03-05T02:44:46.000000Z",
      "is_agency": false,
      "ref": {
        "user_id": 5,
        "code": "OZO33T",
        "agency": false
      }
    }
```

why is the `ref` property being inserted in the collection?
if a remove `$data->append('is_agency');` `ref` disappear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```php
 //change
 public function getIsAgencyAttribute() {
    return isset( $this->ref->agency ) && $this->ref->agency;
 }

 // to this
 public function getIsAgencyAttribute() {
    return isset( $this->ref()->first()->agency ) && $this->ref()->first()->agency;
 }
```